# apt-get upgrade freezes at "Waiting for Headers"

Tags: upgrade, updates

I tried to upgrade my system using `sudo apt-get upgrade` but it's not upgrading. It just shows:

```
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
0% [Waiting for headers].
```

Then it doesn't move forward.

Comment: Probably the Ubuntu mirror you are using is down. If that's the case, you can just wait a few hours and try again, or you can configure your system to use a different mirror (for instance in synaptic: Settings -> Repositories -> Download from:)

Answer (score 0):

Issue Solved,
There was problem with some repository links in sources.list file.I was unable to get updates from google so it was freezing at starting point. After removing the entry for google updates it works fine !!!